# Which vhost causing error request exceeded redirects in error.log

Tags: apache

How can I find out which which virtual host website is causing the error without going through all of my vhosts and change log level?

```
Request exceeded the limit of 40 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, I would start by looking through the access logs at the exact timestamp that the offending redirects are logging in the error log.  From the access log, you can probably at least see referrers to figure out which virtual host is causing it.